# How to understand the notation $f \asymp g$ in probability?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, probability, analysis, notation

> In the probability theory, $f \asymp g$ as $p\to \pi$ if $$\frac{f(p)}{g(p)}$$ is bounded away from 0 and $\infty$ on a neighbourhood of $\pi$.

But in the analysis, 
\begin{align}
f(x) \asymp g(x) \implies \exists c_1,c_2, \text{ such that}\\
c_1|g(x)|\leq |f(x)| \leq c_2|g(x)|
\end{align}

How to show that these two definitions are equivalent?

Comment: If your second expression is true for all $x$ and also $c_1,c_2, f(x),g(x)$ are all greater than $0$ then $c_1$ and $c_2$ are the bounds for your first expression

Comment: Why is this a probability question?  It doesn't look like there's any probability involved here.

Comment: @JairTaylor This is the definition in the Probability textbook.

Comment: @Henry But why do we need $p\to \pi$?

Comment: @Bob - you asked the original question.  I am guessing that $\pi$ is an arbitrary  fixed value rather than $3.14\ldots$